# how to fix github pages show 404

Tags: github

I am access my github pages:https://jiangxiaoqiang.github.io/. But it shows 404 page not found.I am sure about this:

- I am already add index.html in my repo
- The index.html file in the master branch

I read other users solution but still did not understand why my github pages not work.How to fix? By the way, this is my repo source:https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/jiangxiaoqiang.github.io. When I am using this https://jiangxiaoqiang.github.io/index.html. it works.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't show 404 for me, I can see your website

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache or in incognito

Comment: maybe the browser's cache,I am confusing about this.@MickaelB.

Comment: And try with another browser

Comment: I am tried with firefox but still the same..... @MickaelB.